# How to fix jQuery pagination by dynamic generated AJAX-Table

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I'm trying to implement pagination in my app with dynamic table, what I've generated using ajax:

```
  function loadWeekData() {

    // Append database data here

     $.ajax({
         type: "GET",
         url: "/Home/JsonWeekEvents",
         dataType: "JSON",
         success: function (result) {
           $.each(result, function (i, val) {
              var trow = $('<tr/>').data("id", val.Id);
               trow.append('<td style="padding:5px; width:auto; height:60px"class="FSE">'+val.FSE+'</td>');
            trow.append('<td class="tdMon" valign="top" style="padding:1px; text-align:center; width:160px; height:100px;background-color:' + val.MonColor + ';">' +
                '<div class="ui-widget" >' +
                '<input type="button" id="dltBtn" class="dltEvent" size="5" value="-" />' +
                '<input  size="7" maxlength="10" id="tagsM" class="tags" />' +
                '<input type="button" id="addBtn" class="addEvent" size="5" value="+" /><br/>' +
                '<div style="text-align:center;" id="monVal" class="desc_NumM">' + val.Monday + '</div >' +
                '<input  type="hidden" class="idEvent" />' + '<input type="hidden"  class="ColorEventM" value="' + val.MonColor+'" />' +
                '</div >' +
                '</td>');
            trow.append('<td valign="top" style="padding:1px;text-align:center; width:160px; height:100px;background-color:' + val.TueColor + ';">' +
                '<div class="ui-widget">' +
                '<input type="button" id="dltBtn" class="dltEvent" size="5" value="-" />' +
                '<input  size="7" maxlength="10" id="tagsT" class="tags" />' +
                '<input type="button" id="addBtn" class="addEvent" size="5" value="+" /><br/>' +
                '<div style="text-align:center;" id="tueVal" class="desc_NumT">' + val.Tuesday + '</div >' +
                '<input type="hidden" class="idEvent" />' + '<input type="hidden"  class="ColorEventT" value="' + val.TueColor +'" />' +
                '</div >' +
                '</td>');
            trow.append('<td valign="top" style="padding:1px;text-align:center; width:160px; height:100px;background-color:' + val.WedColor + ';">' +
                '<div class="ui-widget">' +
                '<input type="button" id="dltBtn" class="dltEvent" size="5" value="-" />' +
                '<input  size="7" maxlength="10" id="tagsW" class="tags" />' +
                '<input type="button" id="addBtn" class="addEvent" size="5" value="+" /><br/>' +
                '<div style="text-align:center;" id="wedVal" class="desc_NumW">' + val.Wednesday + '</div >' +
                '<input type="hidden" class="idEvent" />' + '<input type="hidden"  class="ColorEventW" value="' + val.WedColor +'" />' +
                '</div >' +
                '</td>');
            trow.append('<td valign="top" style="padding:1px;text-align:center; width:160px; height:100px;background-color:' + val.ThurColor + ';">' +
                '<div class="ui-widget">' +
                '<input type="button" id="dltBtn" class="dltEvent" size="5" value="-" />' +
                '<input  size="7" maxlength="10" id="tagsTr" class="tags" />' +
                '<input type="button" id="addBtn" class="addEvent" size="5" value="+" /><br/>' +
                '<div style="text-align:center;" id="thurVal" class="desc_NumTr">' + val.Thursday + '</div >' +
                '<input type="hidden" class="idEvent" />' + '<input type="hidden"  class="ColorEventThr" value="' + val.ThurColor +'" />' +
                '</div >' +
                '</td>');
            trow.append('<td valign="top" style="padding:1px;text-align:center; width:160px; height:100px;background-color:' + val.FriColor + ';">' +
                '<div class="ui-widget">' +
                '<input type="button" id="dltBtn" class="dltEvent" size="5" value="-" />' +
                '<input  size="7" maxlength="10" id="tagsFr" class="tags" />' +
                '<input type="button" id="addBtn" class="addEvent" size="5" value="+" /><br/>' +
                '<div style="text-align:center;" id="friVal" class="desc_NumF">' + val.Friday + '</div >' +
                '<input type="hidden" class="idEvent" />' + '<input type="hidden"  class="ColorEventF" value="' + val.FriColor +'" />' +
                '</div >' +
                '</td>');
            trow.append('<td valign="top" style="padding:1px;text-align:center; width:170px; height:100px;background-color:' + val.SatColor + ';">' +
                '<div class="ui-widget">' +
                '<input type="button" id="dltBtn" class="dltEvent" size="5" value="-" />' +
                '<input  size="7" maxlength="10" id="tagsSt" class="tags" />' +
                '<input type="button" id="addBtn" class="addEvent" size="5" value="+" /><br/>' +
                '<div style="text-align:center;" id="satVal" class="desc_NumSa">' + val.Saturday + '</div >' +
                '<input type="hidden" class="idEvent" />' + '<input type="hidden"  class="ColorEventSa" value="' + val.SatColor +'" />' +
                '</div >' +
                '</td>');
            trow.append('<td valign="top" style="padding:1px;text-align:center; width:160px; height:100px;background-color:' + val.SunColor + ';">' +
                '<div class="ui-widget">' +
                '<input type="button" id="dltBtn" class="dltEvent" size="5" value="-" />' +
                '<input  size="7" maxlength="10" id="tagsSu" class="tags" />' +
                '<input type="button" id="addBtn" class="addEvent" size="5" value="+" /><br/>' +
                '<div style="text-align:center;" id="sunVal" class="desc_NumSu">' + val.Sunday + '</div >' +
                '<input type="hidden" class="idEvent" />' + '<input type="hidden"  class="ColorEventSu" value="' + val.SunColor +'" />' +
                '</div >' +
                '</td>');
            trow.append('<td  style="padding:2px; width:50px; height:70px"><a href="#" rel="events-week-edit" class="edit">Edit Week</a></td>');
            tbody.append(trow);
            tab.append(tbody);

        });

        //$("tr:odd", tab).css('background-color', '#C4C4C4');

        $("#weekEvents").html(tab);
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("Failed! Please try again.");
    }
});

var tab = $('<table class=MyTable border=1 ></table>');
var thead = $('<thead><tr></tr></thead>');

thead.append('<th style="padding:5px">FSE' + "&nbsp;" + '</th>');
thead.append('<th style="padding:5px">Monday' + "&nbsp;" + '</th>');
thead.append('<th style="padding:5px">Tuesday' + "&nbsp;" + '</th>');
thead.append('<th style="padding:5px">Wednesday' + "&nbsp;" + '</th>');
thead.append('<th style="padding:5px">Thursday' + "&nbsp;" + '</th>');
thead.append('<th style="padding:5px">Friday' + "&nbsp;" + '</th>');
thead.append('<th style="padding:5px">Saturday' + "&nbsp;" + '</th>');
thead.append('<th style="padding:5px">Sunday' + "&nbsp;" + '</th>');
tab.append(thead);

var tbody = $('<tbody id="paginate"></tbody>')
}
```

but somehow I dont recive any rows by their length = "0"

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

loadWeekData();

var show_per_page = 4;
var number_of_items = $('#paginate tr').length;

//navigation bar
var navigation_html = '<a class="previous_link" href="">Prev</a>' + '&nbsp';
var current_link = 1;
for (var i = 0; i < number_of_items; i = i + show_per_page) {
navigation_html += '<a class="page_link" href="" data-start="' + i + '" data-end="' + (i 
+ show_per_page) + '">' + (current_link) + '</a>' + '&nbsp';
    current_link++;
}
navigation_html += '<a class="next_link" href="">Next</a>';
$('#page_navigation').html(navigation_html);
rowDisplay(0, show_per_page);

//Activating of the first page
function rowDisplay(startIndex, endIndex) {
    $('#paginate tr').hide().slice(startIndex, endIndex).show();
}

//Pagination functionylity
$('.page_link').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    var IndexData = $(this).data();
    rowDisplay(IndexData.start, IndexData.end);
}).first().addClass('active');

//"Next" & "Previous" functionality
$('.previous_link, .next_link').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var traverse = $(this).is('.previous_link') ? 'prev' : 'next';
    $('.page_link.active')[traverse]('.page_link').click();
});
});
```

with simple table generated in HTML it works and generate pages and so on, but for some reason it doesn't work with an AJAX table...

can somebody tell me what is my problem?

Answer (score 0):

solved:

my code belongs to loadWeekData() function, right after $("#weekEvents").html(tab);